# Typescript sub-generic type inference

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is this is beyond the abilities of what TypeScript is able to do or am I doing something terribly wrong? Here is some code that I would have like to have working:

```
interface ISquare {
    area: number;
}

interface ICircle {
    radius: number;
}

abstract class Morph<T1, T2> {
    firstOption: T1;
    secondOption: T2;
}

class CircleAndSquare extends Morph<ICircle, ISquare> { }

function returnSecondOption<TMorph extends Morph<T1, T2>, T1, T2> (morph: TMorph): T2 {
    return morph.secondOption;
}

returnSecondOption(new CircleAndSquare()) // adding a . here should give me intellisense for a square
```

The intellisense should show the members of `ISquare` when I put a dot at the end of the function call to `returnSecondOption`, but it doesn't, it seems to see T1 and T2 as `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, `extends` for generic parameter makes for a really weak constraint.

In other words, `TMorph extends Morph<T1, T2>` does not provide enough information to infer that `secondOption` in `TMorph` is always `T2`, because for example `TMorph` can be extended like this:

```
class BadMorph extends Morph<ICircle, ISquare> { 
    secondOption: ISquare & { radius: string }
}
```

and `secondOption` is not really an `ICircle` anymore because `radius` is now `number & string` which is essentially equivalent to `{}`.

Another thing is that `TMorph` generic parameter is not really necessary in `returnSecondOption` as it's currently written in the question, so you can just get rid of it:

```
function returnSecondOption<T1, T2> (morph: Morph<T1, T2>): T2 {
    return morph.secondOption;
}
```

It will take anything compatible with `Morph<T1, T2>` anyway, and inference works

```
let s = returnSecondOption(new CircleAndSquare());
```

in typescript playground is shown with `s: ISquare` tooltip.

I don't know how to make inference work if you really need to have a name in `returnSecondOption` for exact type of its argument. You can try

```
function returnSecondOptionGeneric2<TMorph, T1, T2> (morph: TMorph & Morph<T1, T2>): T2 {
    return morph.secondOption;
}
```

but I'm not sure what this variant allows to do.

Comment: `function returnSecondOption<T1, T2> (morph: Morph<T1, T2>): T2` is correct. I don't see that anything more complex is warranted by the scenario in the OP.